# Drag and slide Android view. Show / Hide full view when user releases touch event in the middle

Tags: android, slider, ontouchlistener

I want to implement a view drag event in my application.

[image]

In the screen above, I want to pin the search bar to the bottom and change the pink layout visibility when I drag the grey slider.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23228740/5675550) is the workaround I did so far. How would I show / hide full view when user releases the touch event in the middle. Like I want to show full view when the use slides up more than 50% of the view and hide the view when user doesn't slide up to 50%

Comment: Why don't you make **Coordinator layout** as parent and make your *pink layout* as `BottomSheet`. In such a way, you can override **`BottomSheetBehavior`** and make adjustments according to your need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I have done it myself using `CordinatorLayout` and a little bit of tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

This is solvable via a BottomSheetBehavior with a CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Yes `BottomSheetBehavior` is the way to go. But I want to show/hide the whole bottom layout on user tap. Is there a way in `BottomSheetBehavior` so that I can slide up/down the pink layout and anchor the search layout at the bottom? And collapse/expand the whole bottom layout on user tap?

Answer (score 0):

In your switch statement try adding a case ACTION_UP:

```
switch (event.getActionMasked()){
     case ACTION_DOWN: //get initial state
     case ACTION_MOVE: //do the sliding
     case ACTION_UP: // slider release
         event.getRawY() // this is the y-point where the slider has been releases --> upper 50% of display: show slider full-screen, lower 50% -> show map full-screen
         break;
}
```

Comment: Please explain futher how would I do it. I mean compare the height with height of slider and show / hide the slider completely.

Comment: Hello Richard, please guide me thorough this.